# Lightning Component not showing on Lightning Tab

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lightning

I am not able to see my lightning component when trying to create a lighting tab. Something is wrong with one of the components -

I moved the component and tab using salesforce dx and when editing the component. I am getting below error. I seems like one of the component is throwing an error when i am trying to edit the record -

Error = Review all error messages below to correct your data.
You can only create lightning tabs for AuraDefinitionBundles containing a component that implements force:appHostable and has no required attributes without a default value. (Related field: Content)

Observation - When i remove the attribute from parent component and child component than its working and i am able to save the tab. Something is not correct with my component initiation.

Code in parent Component -

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!!v.customTab}">
<div aura:id="defaultTabContent" class="slds-show">
    <c:ApiRequestFieldMapping custom="false" objectName="Credit_Report__c"/>
</div>
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.customTab}">
<div aura:id="customTabContent" class="slds-hide">
    <c:ApiRequestFieldMapping custom="true" listSObjects="
    {!v.listSObjects}" message="Select object from drop-down." 
    messageClass="Info"/>
</div>
```

Code in Child Component -

```
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="handleModelVisiblity" type="c:HandleModel"/>
<!-- attributes -->
<aura:attribute name="custom" type="Boolean"/>
<aura:attribute name="objectName" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="listSObjects" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="messageClass" type="String"/> 
<aura:attribute name="listSObjectFields" type="String[]" 
required="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="customObjectName" type="String" 
required="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="listWrapper" 
type="RequestMappingWrapper.MappingRecords[]" required="false"/>
```

Already Tried - 1. My component is already implementing "force:appHostable" interface.
2. The component us using latest version.(40.0)
3. Have already tried creating the components.
4. My org has my domain enabled and also have namespace.

Comment: I have fixed the issue. I have removed the reference to inner class in one of the attribute. Changed "RequestMappingWrapper.MappingRecords[]" to "RequestMappingWrapper[]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. I have removed the reference to inner class in one of the attribute. Changed "RequestMappingWrapper.MappingRecords[]" to "RequestMappingWrapper[]".